# Folding@Home project killing CPU

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, cpu, processor

Three to four weeks ago I read an article which was talking about the project Folding@Home which helps researchers  find a cure for the CoVid-19.

Since then my Mac has been pretty noisy, although the idea was to run the software when I was not working on my Mac. Today I noticed that despite not having so much running on the Mac it is noisy and also kind of hot underneath.

In the iStat, i found out that the FAHclient was taking the most of the CPU power (even when not running it).  I  uninstalled the software and its client is still running in the background.

I also terminated the process related to it in the terminal:

> ps aux | grep fah
>
> kill *the pid*

[image: iStat]

How can I uninstall it completely as it's not letting me concentrate since a while.

Comment: You're missing the terminal command you said you used to terminate the process.

Comment: `ps aux | grep fah (to show all the process related to folding@home)`

`kill  the id of the process '

Comment: Please [edit] the question with that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't deselect the Uninstaller in the installer app, the Folding@home folder also contains an uninstaller.pkg:

[image]

If the *Uninstall Folding@home.pkg* is missing in your environment simply download the [installer](https://download.foldingathome.org/releases/public/release/fah-installer/osx-10.11-64bit/v7.6/fah-installer_7.6.9_x86_64.mpkg.zip) and install Folding@Home again. Then use the *pkg* to uninstall everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, this is expected behavior.

You're "loaning" out unused CPU cycles (or processing power, horsepower, or whatever you want to call it) to someone else to do calculations.  It's going to consume what you allow it to.

The fans coming on is only natural, the more you tax your CPU, the hotter it runs, necessitating the fans coming on.

> I uninstalled the software and its client is still running in the background.

Then it's not fully uninstalled.  The client is still running, means it's still doing it's thing.

To uninstall an app, I suggest using [App Cleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/).  It's "donation-ware" meaning it's free and the dev asks for a small donation to support his work.  It's worth a $5 or $10 donation (IMO).

However, this is a noble endeavor and if the CPU use is too high for your liking, you can "throttle" it to a lower threshold (Light, Medium, Full).

See this really well written Meta Post: [Using Folding@home to help fight COVID-19](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3854/119271) for additional details.

Answer (score 0):

Open your installation location and open the FAHController.app there you will be able to reduce the amount of CPU cores to be dedicated and also pause and continue the process at your will.

Another way to stop folding is to visit http://client.foldingathome.org.

In detail, this is explained in the meta post:
- [Using Folding@home to help fight COVID-19](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/using-foldinghome-to-help-fight-covid-19)